# Masonry not working on images fetched from mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql

My application uploads the images in a folder and save its path in a mysql column. I display those images in the following way..

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM task_table ORDER by RAND()";
    //ORDER BY id ASC
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
          $file = $row['photo_name'];
          $file1 = $row['task_id'];
          $task_details=$row['task_details'];
          echo '<div id="container">
          <div id="thumbnail"><a href="uploads/'. $file .'"  title="'.cleanString($file).'" class="thickbox">
          <img src="thumbnails/thumb_'.$row['task_id'].'.jpeg" width="282" height="158" alt="image" /></a></div>
          <div id="info"><strong>' .cleanString($file).'</strong></br>
          <i>' .cleanString($task_details).'</i></div>
          </div>';
    }
```

Here is the javascript with 'thumbnail' as itemselector

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

       <script>
       //<![CDATA[$(window).load(function()
       {
          $(function(){

          $('#container').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.thumbnail'
       });

       });
       });//]]>  
       </script>
```

The Gallery shows as a usual grid but unlike masonry. Where did I go wrong? Pardon me if my post is in wrong category or I made few posting mistakes for this is my first post in stackoverflow :-)

**SOLUTION**

```
       <script>
         //<![CDATA[ 
         $(window).load(function(){
         $(function(){

         $('#container').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.thickbox'
          });

          });
          });//]]>  
       </script>
```

.....and mysql queries

```
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
         {
           $file = $row['photo_name'];
       $file1 = $row['task_id'];
       $task_details=$row['task_details'];
       echo '<div id="container">
       <div class="thumbnail"><div class="thickbox">
       <img src="uploads/'. $file .'" alt="image"/></div>
       <div id="info"><strong>' .cleanString($file).'</strong></br>
       <i>' .cleanString($task_details).'</i></div>
       </div>';
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one use class `thickbox` for divs and **id** should be unique in html elements change **id"container",id="thumbnail"** to class as well because  you are looping through the elements

```
$(function(){

          $('#container').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.thickbox'
       });
```

[**masonry itemselector**](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#itemselector)

Comment: tried your changes in the following manner..                                        echo '<div id="container"><div class="container"><div class="container">             didn't work.

Comment: Just tried your and PiotrK's solution and both are working !!! thanks guys. I will add my solution below my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your DIVs a **class**, not an ID. Look at your `itemSelector`, it's `'.thumbnail'`. The dot means it refers to the class "thumbnail".

Just try to change `<div id="thumbnail">` to `<div class="thumbnail">`.

Comment: Changed id to class. Didn't work. Is it because all my thumbnails are of equal size ?

Comment: Ah, they are? So please explain us what effect you want to achieve. AFAIK, Masonry does something with the content only when the containers have various sizes.

Comment: Just to inform other viewers that your solution is working too.It turns out I had some problem with mysql queries. Thanks. Cant vote you up and cant chose more than 1 "accept answer".